# Gradle is not downloaded while building the project in Jenkins

Tags: android, git, github, jenkins, gradle

I get the following error when I build the apk in Jenkins.

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace E:\jenkins\workspace\Testing
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ config remote.origin.url https://github.com/advanced1989/JenkinsTest.git/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/advanced1989/JenkinsTest.git/
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/advanced1989/JenkinsTest.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5efbaeab04975ae97eb75a1a410380af0cefbaca (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ checkout -f 5efbaeab04975ae97eb75a1a410380af0cefbaca
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe\ rev-list 5efbaeab04975ae97eb75a1a410380af0cefbaca # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
FATAL: Failed to install https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4-rc-2-bin.zip to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation\Gradle
java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4-rc-2-bin.zip to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation\Gradle
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:854)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:762)
    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:76)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:72)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation.forNode(GradleInstallation.java:89)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.performTask(Gradle.java:236)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.perform(Gradle.java:152)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:775)
    ... 17 more
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please let me know why the gradle is not downloaded.
It is very specific to my environment I tried it in other system it worked fine.
Very new to Jenkins build

Comment: It could be that you or jenkins temporarily lost your/its internet connection.  Try building again.

Comment: No, I tried it just now. same issue

Comment: It's definitely a connection issue.

Comment: Do you maybe have to use some Proxy that is not configured?

Comment: I changed my location it worked but now issue is different.

Comment: 19:07:46.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

Comment: 19:04:39.643 [INFO] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443: Connection reset
19:04:39.653 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec] Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Please let me know if you require the complete error log.